# AWK / SCRIPT , return number of values from specific field in the /etc/group file

Tags: linux, bash, awk

Im trying to write somthing that will give me this type of output using ***awk***.

I'm trying to extract the **group name** , the **group ID** and the **numbers of users** in each group from the **/etc/group** file

```
Group : root    ID:0 : 2 accounts 

Group : daemon  ID:  1  : 1 account

Group : bin  ID:  2  : 1 account
```

Ive tried this for now ,

```
#!/bin/bash    
NbrsUtil=$(cut -d ":" -f4 /etc/group | awk -F "," '{print NF}')



awk -v utils=$NbrsUtil  -F ":"  '{print "Groupe:",$1,"ID:" $3,utils," :accounts"} ' /etc/group
```

This is not working ..
i can try to use "cut" to specify the field i want , and then I use awk to count the number of fiels via the "|" , and i get the good values but the output is not good and does not work with my script.

```
cut -d ":" -f4 /etc/group | awk -F "," '{print NF}'
0
0
0
0
2
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
2
0
```

If i echo the command in the script it show in one line

```
#!/bin/bash

NbrsUtil=$(cut -d ":" -f4 /etc/group | awk -F "," '{print NF}')
echo $NbrsUtil
awk   -F ":"  '{print "Groupe:",$1,"ID:" $3,$4," :accounts"} ' /etc/group
```

-->

```
0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 1 1 0 1 2 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 2 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0
Groupe: root ID:0  :accounts
Groupe: daemon ID:1  :accounts
Groupe: bin ID:2 :accounts
Groupe: sys ID:3 :accounts
Groupe: adm ID:4 franco,root :accounts
Groupe: tty ID:5 :accounts
Groupe: disk ID:6 :accounts
Groupe: lp ID:7 :accounts
Groupe: mail ID:8 :accounts
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`awk` has a `split` function that can help:

> **split(s, a[, fs  ])**
> Split the string `s` into array elements `a[1]`, `a[2]`, ..., `a[n]`, and **return** `n`. *[...]* The separation shall be done with the ERE `fs` or with the field separator `FS` if `fs` is not given.

So you can just do:

```bash
awk -F: '{print "Group:",$1,"ID:",$3,"Accounts:",split($4,_,",")}' /etc/group
```

Comment: This solved my issue thanks , my only question is , what does the underscore mean ? Is it just the name of the array ?

Comment: Yes, it's the name of the array variable required by the `split` function; it's a kind of common practice to use an `_` for showing that a variable/argument isn't used for anything

Comment: Thanks for the input , didn't know the Split function existed for awk . Useful

Comment: You're welcome. Here's a list of the standard "string functions" in `awk` https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_13_13 . GNU/BSD/etc `awk` got more ones but they're not standardized, so I tend to not use them because my little scripts are generally meant for various OSs

Comment: better yet, change the last part about split to :::::::::::::::::::: ::::::::::::::::::: ::::::::::: ::::::::::::::::::::::: ::::::::::::::: :::::::::::::::: gsub(  / [ , ] / , " & " ,  $ 4 ) + 1  ::::::::(only spacing things for readability - it's more light weight approach for same result without incurring cost of physically splitting the array out

Comment: ps : current rendition of nawk in BSD in horridly buggy :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: nawk 'BEGIN { print ( "\2" ~ "\0" ), ( "\0" == "\0\2" ) }' :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: that would actually print out true for both : it's ghastly, it's deplorable, it's the pile for the landfill

Answer (score 1):

You might also use:

```
awk -F: '{
  nr = ($4 == "") ? 0 : gsub(/,/, "", $4) + 1
  print "Groupe:",$1,"ID:",$3,"Accounts:", nr " :accounts"
}' /etc/group
```

Or a bit shortened version as suggested by [RARE Kpop Manifesto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14672114/rare-kpop-manifesto):

```
awk -F: '{
  nr = ( "" < $4 ) + gsub(/,/, "", $4)
  print "Groupe:",$1,"ID:",$3,"Accounts:", nr " :accounts"
}' /etc/group
```

The `nr` in the script is zero when `$4` is empty.

If it is not empty, you can replace all the comma's using `gsub` and that will return the number of replacements.

Add 1 to the result of gsub as when it is not empty but also not comma's, there is still 1 account.

Which gives a result like:

```
Groupe: root ID: 0 Accounts: 0 :accounts
Groupe: daemon ID: 1 Accounts: 0 :accounts
Groupe: bin ID: 2 Accounts: 0 :accounts
Groupe: sys ID: 3 Accounts: 0 :accounts
Groupe: adm ID: 4 Accounts: 2 :accounts
Groupe: tty ID: 5 Accounts: 1 :accounts
```

Comment: maybe condense it even further like :::::::   nr = ( "" < $4 ) + gsub(/,/, "", $4) :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: :::: (my comment in the other post should've remembered to handle the blank line special case) ( changing ( $4 ~ "." ) to ( "" < $4 ) since string compare is cheaper computationally than regex)

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto Thank you for your comment, that looks promising. So if I am not mistaken, comparing strings with `<` is based on the length of the strings?

Comment: " < " alone is string compare  based on locale-specific character ordinance values, compared one position at a time, until there's no longer a tie, which can be peculiar at times, e.g. ( "55" < "6" ) is true. In the example above, i'm comparing $4 against empty string, so as long as $4 has anything in it, it would be true. it's another way of writing ( $4 != "" ) or ( $4 ~ "." ) or ( $4 !~ /^$/ ). upside of string cmp is that you can always prepend a very strange byte ( or byte sequence) to each side of the comparison, something like \374 or \301 or  \23\32 , to override any attempts of

Comment: ….. of gawk trying to do locale-specific string compare, or by unicode official collation order, but directly via by byte-ordinance ranking instead. for my own codes, to check whether a leading byte of a string is ascii or not, i actually do ( str  < "\200" ), far faster than any regex or table lookup. but the reverse of checking for leading byte of string being 8-bit byte, it must be done via  ( "\200" <= str ) and not ( "\177" < str ),  since ( "\177" < "\177abc") is true. use ( "\177" < x ) only if you're very certain x is a single byte

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto Thank you for your thorough explanation, I will add the version with your suggestion as well.